# State Machine - Is enum the choice for states?

Tags: objective-c, enums, state

I would like to have class static variables as states, but Objective C disallowed it

I tried `+(int)LOOPING_STATE` for state class, but it will fail in

```
switch (myCurrentState) {
case [STATE_CLASS LOOPING_STATE]:   <== received an error of "expression can't be put here"
return;
}
```

Is enum generally the choice for writing state codes?

Are there any other options, and under what condition should those options be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this state machine needs to be fast, enums are the way to go.  However, if you want an object oriented way of doing this, the functionality of each state would be a method of the state object itself.  Thus you would do away with the switch/if statement altogether.  Your state machine's loop would look something like this:

```
-(void) run
{
    State* currentState;

    currentState = [self startState];
    while (currentState != [self stopState])
    {
        currentState = [currentState transitionWitInput: inputs 
                                                actions: actions];
    }
}
```

`inputs` is the input data for the state transition, `actions` is a block or a selector or an `NSInvocation` or something that tells the state what to do during the transition.

Answer (score 4):

This has little to do with Objective-C but more with the C in Objective-C. In general, using an enum to represent the states of your state machine should be preferred over plain integers.

The reason you can't use classes in a switch is that the value of the expressions used in the case labels of a switch statement need to be known at compile time. Assuming `[STATE_CLASS LOOPING_STATE]` is an invocation of a class method, the compiler can't safely know the result of that expression at compile time, and will thus refuse generating a switch statement.

Why does the compiler require knowing the result of expressions used for case labels at compile time? The idea behind a switch statement is to be more efficient than a series of semantically equivalent if/else if blocks. This is achieved by translating a switch statement into a dispatch table with an unconditional jump, whereas the if/else if solution requires lots of conditional jumps. As one can easily guess, conditional jumps are fundamentally at odds with modern pipelined CPU designs since they may cause the entire pipeline to be flushed. (Modern CPUs try to compensate with sophisticated branch prediction, but it would be better if we can avoid the issue altogether, right?)

But then, getting it right comes first, making it fast second.

Comment: Many thx for the explain. I hate global constant defined by enum, is there a way to put the state constant under a class? Or is there other options to do what I want? Thanks!

Comment: Declaring an enum inside the header of your statemachine should be fine, after all the number of states should be finite anyway. I don't see an issue with the enum defining these constants globally (after all, your only interested in the symbols, not the values).